# Using rsync with gitlab-ci how to deploy identically?

Tags: symfony, ssh, gitlab-ci, rsync

when I push and that, on my server, I don't have my project, everything is fine (obviously):

```
rsync --exclude=".git" -e ssh -avz --delete-after . $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:blog_symfony/
building file list ... done
created directory blog_symfony
[...]
sent 44,533,927 bytes  received 5,523 bytes  5,239,935.29 bytes/sec
total size is 238,959,003  speedup is 5.37
```

the problem when I push a 2nd time, it does anything to me:

```
rsync: [generator] delete_file: rmdir(project/blog_symfony/project/blog_symfony) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: [generator] delete_file: rmdir(project/blog_symfony) failed: Permission denied (13)
deleting project/blog_symfony/translations/.gitignore
deleting project/blog_symfony/translations/
[...]
```

it creates for me, on my server side, a 'project' folder in the blog_symfony folder

```
annot delete non-empty directory: project/blog_symfony
cannot delete non-empty directory: project
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
sent 13,924 bytes  received 175 bytes  28,198.00 bytes/sec
total size is 238,959,004  speedup is 16,948.65
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

my gitlab-ci:

```
before_script:
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" >> ~/.ssh/config'
    script:
        - ls
        - apt-get update && apt-get install rsync -y
        - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "ls"
        - rsync --exclude=".git" -e ssh -avz --delete-after . $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:blog_symfony/
        - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd blog_symfony && docker-compose build && docker-compose up"
```

in ls -l I have a folder written by rsync and which is impossible to remove from gitlab-ci:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 root                     root                        4096 Dec 14 23:26  project
```

I don't think this is normal. This is the first time that I use gitlab-ci for a symfony project.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ls -l`: I have a folder written by `rsync` and which is impossible to remove from GitLab CI.

Check if that folder is instead created after the first execution of your `docker-compose up`: if your Docker image execute itself internally as `USER root`, using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), it would write files/folders as `root`.
And that would impede normal operation (on the server, outside the container), like your `rsync`, because root files would be i the way.

Comment: indeed... I searched everywhere except the docker line...
so i deleted and it works.. thanks.
but now how to build and launch symfony (create the database, etc) in the container via gitlab-ci? Unless my approach is wrong and I have to go through docker registry?!

Comment: @Camel4488 It depends which line you deleted. `USER root`? Or the bind mount? Because if you delete the mount, then all data would be written in the container, and would be ephemeral (deleted when the container stops and is removed)

Comment: - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd blog_symfony && docker-compose build && docker-compose up" I deleted this line. I'm just trying to set up my gitlab for production, but I'm a little lost... (to do something clean, stable, secure and persistent

Comment: @Camel4488 Then you can start and follow a process similar to "[Setting up Symfony continuous integration using GitLab CI/CD](https://medium.com/@zakariae/setting-up-symfony-continuous-deployment-using-rancher-274838fcf632)". See if it is close to what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I have the gitlab-runner install on my server. I am trying to set up the deploy (for the moment). so the best is to build the docker image with gitlab-ci then push it to the production server? (and not do as I do i.e. push the code to the production server and compile the docker image)?

Comment: @Camel4488 Yes, building the image, and pushing it to the production server would be a good way for said production server to `docker run` it. No need for that production server to build anything, just to run what it is supposed to run.

Comment: Ok but gitlab-ci must also tell it symfony console make:migration (...) symfony server -d etc do we agree on this logic?because I can't find many tutorials this way

Comment: @Camel4488 That I do not know, not having enough experience with Symfony.